# what is the terminal code to find installed software/application path?

Tags: linux

Recently I installed sublime text 3. I want to add some syntax highlighting packages but I cannot find the path of this application.

How could I find the location of this application?

Comment: This belongs on another stackexchange website, unix/linux most likely

Comment: Oops... !! ll go there

Comment: In any case, I think you'll find the answer to your question below

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `locate` to look for finding files by name

See https://linux.die.net/man/1/locate

You would do: -

> locate sublime

Example: -

```
[myuser@svr~]$ locate visudo
/usr/sbin/visudo
/usr/share/man/man8/visudo.8.gz
```

As the post I link below suggests, you may need to run `sudo updatedb` to update your database if it hasn't been set up already.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/124757/how-to-update-linux-locate-cache

Comment: this code locate sublime showing nothing.. my linux version is 16 something

Comment: Will probably need more information about how it was installed, what distribution of linux you're using and so on. Perhaps, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/256854/where-is-sublime-text-2-installed